# Cloudflare worker: How to modify a response body like a string?

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to detect some string in the response body just to log a message to the console.
In another part of the code I also try to `replace` a piece of text in the response body.

These two attempts are throwing errors in the worker:

```
   if (response.body.includes("X")) {
        console.log(response.body);
   }
```

And:

```
    responseCopy = new Response(response.body, response)
    responseCopy.body = responseCopy.body.replace("x", "y")
```

How can I:

1. Check for the existence of a piece of text in the response body and act accordingly?
2. Manipulate the response body like a string, e.g. replace a string, or overwrite it completely?

P.s. I'm really not that keen with js. I can't understand why it's not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

After researching more, I found out I have to make the function (in which the code is running) `async`, and then `await` on the response. Only then the `text` property of the response (not the `body` (*why?*)) contains the body text:

```
    var html = await response.text()

    // Simple replacement regex
    html = html.replace(/x/g , 'y')
    // return modified response
    return new Response(html, response)
```

Also, the regex replacement should be used, otherwise only the first encounter of the search string is replaced (why js, why?!!).

Comment: instead you could use replaceAll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll 

text() converts the body to text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text 
it is a convenient function, so that you don't need to extract the body convert it and so on.

Comment: For rewriting HTML specifically, you might check out Cloudflare's HTMLRewriter API, which lets you do this in a streaming way (performs better): https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter/